# Creating Shell and History

Tags: c, shell, operating-system

I'm following through *Operating System Concepts 9th Edition* by Silberschatz, Galvin and Gagne. I have gotten to the first project on Chapter 3 where they're asking us to create a UNIX Shell and History Feature. They suggest breaking the project down into 2 parts: 1) Creating the child process and executing the command in the child, and 2) modifying the shell to allow a history feature -- I haven't gotten to 2 yet because I haven't finished/figured out all of 1 and am looking for some help. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80 /* the maximum length command */

void parse(char *line, char **argv) {
    while (*line != '\0') {
        while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n') 
            *line++ = '\0';
        *argv++ = line;
        while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' &&
                *line != '\t' && *line != '\n') line++;
    }
    *argv = '\0';
}

void execute(char **argv) {
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        if (execvp(*argv, argv) < 0) {
            printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        while (wait(&status) != pid);
    }
}


int main(void) {
    char *argv[MAX_LINE / 2 + 1]; /* command line arguments */
    int should_run = 1; /* flag to determine when to exit program */
    char line[1024];

    while (should_run) {
        printf("osh>");
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
        printf("\n");
        parse(line, argv);
        if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0) exit(0);
        execute(argv);

        /**
        *   After reading user input, the steps are;
        *   (1) fork a child process using fork()
        *   (2) the child process will invoke execvp()
        *   (3) if command included &, paren will invoke wait()
        **/
    }



    return 0;
}
```

When I run `cat main.c` (my file's name) I receive almost the correct output; it prints out my main.c and then also reads `'': No such file or directory`. I'm also confused if I were to run `ps -ael` in the terminal (without my program running) I get a bunch of data printed to the terminal. If I run it in my new shell I receive `error: garbage option` and then `Usage: ...`

I'm looking for some help as to what I did wrong here. I know my program also doesn't correctly (or at all) handle if the user types `&` to determine whether or not the parent process should wait for the child to exit...

Comment: The pointer `*argv` does not appears to be properly _null character_ terminated after `while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' &&
                *line != '\t' && *line != '\n') line++;`  Perhaps a `*line = '\0'` after the `while()`?